# Does gender theory explain gender in linguistics?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, language

Considering that one of the roots of Gender theory lies in linguistics via Derrida through deconstruction and subversion; and that Man as a subject not only thinks but also speaks (and possibly spoke before he thought) does it have any explanatory value in understanding gender in a language not as a grammatical category but as gendered language?

Answer (score 1):

In roman languages, the "sun" has masculin gender (il sole), while the moon is feminine (la lune). Yet, in german, it is the other way: "die Sonne", "der Mond".

If gender in language was not (only) a grammatical category, one would have to explain this.